# Remove/Replace Characters in parsed JSON-output in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: json, azure, csv, azure-logic-apps

Bonjour!

Is there a function for removing/replacing all of a specific character in a JSON in Azure Logic Apps?

I am working with a HTTP request in Azure Logic Apps. The results I would like to see is a unnested JSON as a CSV-file.

My steps looks like this:
1.HTTP GET -> 
2.Parse JSON -> 
3.CSV-file

The parsed JSON contains alot of nested values which I would like to transform to columns instead.

My idea is to delete the "{" and "}" characters from the JSON before handling it as a CSV-file which I hope will result in success.

A small example of the structure:

```
"data": [
       "consumption_stats": {
                            "energy": {
                                "hour": {
                                    "count": 27745,
```

So my question is: how can I, in Azure Logic Apps, remove/replace these characters before I make it to an CSV-file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a replace function built into Logic Apps. You could simply replace the characters with an empty string? 
Click "Add Dynamic Content" then go to the expression tree and type "Replace".